# Why does Antelope (a sensor-network DBMS) do an inverse select in order to remove tuples?

Tags: dbms, antelope

Antelope ([a database management system [DBMS for brevity] which enables a sensor to act as a database server](http://anrg.usc.edu/contiki/index.php/Antelope(Database_Management_System)_-_Contiki)) claims that its remove operation is like a swap between two tables. It does an inverse select of the tuples, assigns the result to a new relation (table), removes the old relation (table), and finally renames that new relation (table) with the older name.

> "The Remove Operation. Data tuples can be deleted through the REMOVE
>   operation. This operation takes a condition of the same syntax as is
>   used by SELECT, and removes all tuples matching the condition.
>   Internally, Antelope translates this operation to a SELECT query, with
>   an inverse condition, and assigns the result into a temporary
>   relation. The old relation is then removed, and the temporary relation
>   takes the name of the old relation. Hence, the cost of the REMOVE is
>   comparable to that of a SELECT with an assignment, given an equal
>   number of tuples to process." ([A Database in every sensor](http://dunkels.com/adam/tsiftes11database.pdf))

I know that they use FLASH memory card on each sensor node and have a database on each sensor node. But why do they do an inverse select instead of removing everything they need once? Isn't that more costly?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Likely because of Flash memory limitations. It says in the same pdf that in-place updates are prohibited. so, even if they managed to do a delete in-place, the result would be holes that can't be reused.

Comment: humm. I see, now I understand what they mean about in-place updates are prohibited. Thanks